# Django url template tag refers to url with trailing question mark

Tags: django

This is a question concerning a trailing question mark that gets appended to the end of the URL rendered by Django's `url` template tag. My goal is to have this trailing question mark removed, yet I do not know how.

On my site's main page, I have a button - a `form` HTML tag, really - that directs me to another link of the website.

The form looks like:

```
<form action={% url 'my_index' %}>
   <input type="submit" value="some value" />
</form>
```

When clicking on that button, I am directed to the URL corresponding to the `my_index` view. The problem, however, is that at the end of that URL, there is a "/?" that is appended - that is, the URL is in the form "http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/?". I want to **remove this /?** at the end and also want to understand why this trailing question mark got appended.

My `urls.py` pointed to by the ROOT_URLCONF IS

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('my_app.urls')),
]
```

And my `urls.py` within `my_app` app looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='my_index'),
]
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are making an GET request (default for a form) with just a submit button but without an input value. After the ? you would normally see the input values that you send with the GET request like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/?my_value=12345
```

As your form is empty there is no parameter appended.
You could use a

```
<a href='{% url 'my_index' %}'>
```

if you just want to call a page without any parameter

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an empty form. The default method of your form is GET. So the “?” is necessary to send the form...

Why don’t you use a normal link instead an empty form?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it has to do with my utter inexperience with web dev, I suppose...